# Why is the upper critical dimension of the Ising model 4?

Tags: ising-model, critical-phenomena, mean-field-theory

I have read in various sources, that the critical exponents of the Ising Model are identical to the meanfield ones for dimensions $d \geq 4$. In trying to understand this better I came across the [Ginzburg Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg_criterion) and the concept of [upper critical dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_dimension#Upper_critical_dimension_in_field_theory). I'm new to this field and unfortunately not able to see $d_\text{crit} = 4$ starting from the definition of the Ising Model. Do you have a literature suggestion, where this is derived in a beginner-friendly fashion? Or can you give me a hint on how the Wikipedia page on the upper critical dimension could be related to the Ising Model?

Comment: Try Cardy - Scaling and renormalization in statistical physics, Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 2):

The ideas that you would need to understand this  clearly are Renormalization and Power counting.

The mean field theory by it's very nature ignore all the fluctuation in the field. In the landau energy, the term which would take fluctuations into account is $\nabla\phi$, under renormalization this term becomes smaller for $d>4$ which makes the terms of that kind "irrelevant".