# Question about the so-called upper critical dimension

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena, mean-field-theory

It is often said that above the upper critical dimension, the mean field theory is correct. What is the precise meaning of this statement? Let us be specific and consider the $d$-dimensional Ising model on a hypercubic lattice. It is claimed that the upper critical dimension is $d=4$.

What does this mean?

Does it mean that the mean field theory can get the critical temperature $T_c$ right? Or just the critical exponents right?

Comment: The critical exponents. The value of $T_c$ depends on all kinds of short-distance details and is not universal at all.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257500/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394290/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/412196/2451